# How to escape the curly braces in an Angular template?

Tags: angular

Say I want to display the following string - including the `{{  }}` - in an Angular 2+ template:

```html
Hello {{name}}, how are you?"
```

NB. The whole string will be hard-coded, it won't come from a variable.

What's the best way to escape the curly braces so that they're not considered an interpolation?

I have something that works but it doesn't look super clean:

```html
Hello {{ '{{' }}name}}, how are you?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is special built-in attribute `ngNonBindable` that can be applied like:

```html
<ng-container ngNonBindable>
  Hello {{name}}, how are you?"
</ng-container>
```

or

```html
<div ngNonBindable>
  Hello {{name}}, how are you?"
</div>
```

if you have some container

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/r8RdoeQL89gNz23k3LNe?p=preview)**

Comment: This applies to AngularJS only, no? (my question is for Angular2+)

Comment: Yes, i know it is about angular2

Comment: Thanks, it works. Too bad `ngNonBindable` doesn't show up in the [API Reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/).

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2236#issuecomment-245529288