# Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular from scratch and I am very new. Please forgive me if my question is very simple. I have done research but those solutions did not work for me. I have a app.component.html which contains the below code:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'

<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "name">
<p>{{ name }}</p> // I have tried {{ '{' }} name {{'}'} as suggested in other forums.
```

then I have a app.component.ts file which contains:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '' ;
}
```

I am using Angular CLI to handle building the code. 
But I am not sure why I get below error.

﻿

```
compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("

<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
[ERROR ->]"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@7:0
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("

<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>

[ERROR ->]"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@7:0
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate (compiler.es5.js:14128)
    at compiler.es5.js:14114
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1679)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateOnly (compiler.es5.js:14114)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.es5.js:14096)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15125)
    at compiler.es5.js:26802
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.es5.js:26801
syntaxError @   compiler.es5.js:1690
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeLoadedTemplate @   compiler.es5.js:14128
(anonymous) @   compiler.es5.js:14114
then    @   compiler.es5.js:1679
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateOnly   @   compiler.es5.js:14114
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate   @   compiler.es5.js:14096
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata   @   compiler.es5.js:15125
(anonymous) @   compiler.es5.js:26802
(anonymous) @   compiler.es5.js:26801
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules    @   compiler.es5.js:26798
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @   compiler.es5.js:26768
webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync  @   compiler.es5.js:26697
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone   @   core.es5.js:4536
webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule    @   core.es5.js:4522
../../../../../src/main.ts  @   main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap ac0793c…:54
0   @   main.bundle.js:182
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap ac0793c…:54
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap ac0793c…:25
(anonymous)
```

I really appreciate any help.
Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape the curly braces in an Angular template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516548/how-to-escape-the-curly-braces-in-an-angular-template)

Comment: Since you have doubled curly braces, the correct escape is `{{ '{{' }}` not `{{ '{' }}` as you have tried. BTW, what happened when you used `{{ '{' }}`?

Comment: thanks Ken, but it didn't work.  I changed my code to some thing like   <p> {{  '{{'  }} name {{ '}}' } </p> but it still not working. It gives some red swirl underneath or my code and generates error

Comment: @user1836957 is there a reason for wanting the import statements in the template? They should only be in the component.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about escaping curly braces, based on vary low information that you have provided in the question, you have most likely one of these cases:

- unbalanced double curly braces
- using an statement which is not valid for the compiler

For you the latter should be the case, so fix it by removing the `import` statements from the template to the component.

Edit:

To be more specific, you have statements like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

in you template, so for the compiler import is just a simple text and then it sees the first `{` and then FormsModule. Now, the compiler expects another `{` based on the best match it finds. So, you have a mixture of both, using an statement which has no meaning in the context of a template and based on that you have unbalanced curly braces.

Comment: Thanks Mok, do you mean I need to remove the whole import statement, but when I do that I get error on this line of code: <input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "name">. saying can not to bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

Comment: @user1836957 Import`FormsModule` in your root module.

Answer (score 0):

*Import* statements do not belong into the html file (template). Move them from *app.component.html* to *app.component.ts*:

*app.component.html*:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] = "name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

*app.component.ts*:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '' ;
}
```